# Toggling device toolbar executes link on click button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created this fixed position box that has a mouseover and mouseleave effect using JS, and when we reach 991 viewport pixels, I try to add a toggle effect to display the box using buttons. However, when I activate the "Toggle Device Toolbar" effect, tapping the buttons (in my case, the second button) executes the given link within the div below it, even though the "toggle-download" button is outside of the div that has the link? I tried for hours using different methods but couldn't figure out a solution.
here is a Link to my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d2yc7srf/11/)
[image]

```js
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        // Get both toggle buttons and their corresponding boxes
        var toggleContactButton = document.getElementById('toggle-contact');
        var toggleDownloadButton = document.getElementById('toggle-download');


        var contact = document.getElementById('contact');
        var download = document.getElementById('download');

        var contactBox = document.getElementById('contact-box');
        var downloadBox = document.getElementById('download-box');

        // Function to add active class for a box and button
        function addActiveClass(box, button) {
            box.classList.add('active');
            button.classList.add('active');
        }

        // Function to remove active class for a box and button
        function removeActiveClass(box, button) {
            box.classList.remove('active');
            button.classList.remove('active');
        }

        // Function to toggle active class for a box and button
        function toggleActiveClass(box, button) {
            box.classList.toggle('active');
            button.classList.toggle('active');
        }

        toggleContactButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            toggleActiveClass(contactBox, toggleContactButton);
        });

        toggleDownloadButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            toggleActiveClass(downloadBox, toggleDownloadButton);
        });

        // Add hover event listener for the 'contact' box
        contact.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
            addActiveClass(contactBox, toggleContactButton);
        });

        contact.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
            removeActiveClass(contactBox, toggleContactButton);
        });

        // Add hover event listener for the 'download' box
        download.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
            addActiveClass(downloadBox, toggleDownloadButton);
        });


        download.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
            removeActiveClass(downloadBox, toggleDownloadButton);
        });
    });
```

```css
body{
  background-color: gray;
}
section.quicknavigation {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 999;
    transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

.quicknavigation_container{
    position: inherit;
    top: inherit;
    transform: inherit;
    z-index: inherit;
    transition:inherit;
    right: inherit;
}

section.quicknavigation.rechts {
    right: 0px;
}

section.quicknavigation.links {
    left: 0;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_item {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #fff;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: -150px;
}

.box-content {
    width: 50%;
}

.contact-box,
.download-box {
    width: 300px;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.toggle-slide-button {
    display: none;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transform: translateX(0);
    margin-left: -90px;
    background: #ececec;
    border: 2px solid #21476a;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 70px;
}

.toggle-slide-button svg, img{
    width: 20px;
}


.contact-box.active,
.download-box.active,
.toggle-slide-button.active{
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform: translateX(-150px);
}

.contact-box.active .box-content,
.download-box.active .box-content{
    width: 100%;
}

section.quicknavigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.quicknavigation_social_item_mystery {
    display: none;
}

.contact-box.active .quicknavigation_social_item_mystery {
    display: block;
}

.contact-box.active .quicknavigation_social_container {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.contact-box.active .quicknavigation_untere_box_container {
    padding: 0px;
}

.contact-box.active .quicknavigation_social_item_mystery {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.contact-box.active .quicknavigation_social_item a {
    display: flex;
}

.contact-box.active .quicknavigation_container {
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
}



section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_item:not(:last-child) {
    padding: 30px 0;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_item img {
    width: auto;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_text {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_item_content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 15px;
}



section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_image_container {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_image_container svg,
section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_image_container img {
    /*  width: 65%; */
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    object-fit: cover;

}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_social_container {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 35px;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_social_container svg {
    fill: #82afd7;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_untere_box_image_container svg {
    fill: #ea1b28;
    transition: fill .4s;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_item_content {
    color: #82afd7;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_untere_box_container {
    padding: 30px 0;
    transition: background .4s;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_untere_box_container:hover {
    background: #ea1b28;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_untere_box_container .quicknavigation_text_container {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_untere_box_container .quicknavigation_text_container * {
    color: #ea1b28;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transition: color .4s;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_untere_box_container:hover .quicknavigation_text_container * {
    color: #fff;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_untere_box_container:hover .quicknavigation_untere_box_image_container svg {
    fill: #fff;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_social_item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_social_item[data-type="telefon"] svg,
section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_social_item[data-type="telefon"] img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_social_item[data-type="email"] svg,
section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_social_item[data-type="email"] img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 25px;
    overflow: visible;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_social_item[data-type="facebook"] svg,
section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_social_item[data-type="facebook"] img {
    width: 9px;
    height: 17px;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_social_item[data-type="instagram"] svg,
section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_social_item[data-type="instagram"] img {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_social_item svg {
    transition: fill .4s;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_social_item a:hover svg {
    fill: #115a9e;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_untere_box_image_container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_untere_box_image_container svg,
section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_untere_box_image_container img {
    width: 15px;
    height: 17px;
}

section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_text_container *,
section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_item_content {
    text-align: center;
}

.contact{
    display: flex;
}

.download{
    display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_item {
        display: none;
    }

    section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_item.active {
        display: block;
    }

    .toggle-slide-button {
        display: block;
    }
  section.quicknavigation .quicknavigation_item{
    border-radius: 0px;
  }

}
```

```html
<section class="quicknavigation rechts" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div class="quicknavigation_container">
        <div class="contact" id="contact">
            <button class="toggle-slide-button" id="toggle-contact">
                <svg class="quicknavigation_social_icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 360 360">.</svg>
            </button>

            <div class="quicknavigation_item contact-box" id="contact-box">
                <div class="box-content">
                    <div class="quicknavigation_image_wrapper">
                        <div class="quicknavigation_image_container">
                            <img class="quicknavigation_image" alt="" title="Smiling young woman wearing microphone headset" src="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="quicknavigation_item_content">how can i help you?</p>

                    <div class="quicknavigation_social_container">
                        <div class="quicknavigation_social_item" data-type="telefon">
                            <a href="tel:+49895306222">
                                <svg class="quicknavigation_social_icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 360 360">.</svg>
                                <span class="quicknavigation_social_item_mystery">123 22 22 234</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="quicknavigation_social_item" data-type="email">
                            <a href="mailto:email@email.something">
                                <svg class="quicknavigation_social_icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 360">.</svg>
                                <span class="quicknavigation_social_item_mystery">example@email.com</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="download" id="download">
            <button class="toggle-slide-button" id="toggle-download" href="">
                <svg class="quicknavigation_social_icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 426.67 512">.</svg>
                <a href=""></a>
            </button>

            <div class="quicknavigation_item download-box" id="download-box">
                <!-- Add these buttons inside each box -->
                <div class="box-content">
                    <a href="/downloadcenter/">
                        <div class="quicknavigation_untere_box_container">
                            <div class="quicknavigation_text_container">
                                <p>to Download Center</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="quicknavigation_untere_box_image_container">
                                <svg class="quicknavigation_social_icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 426.67 512">
                                    <use href="http://examplewebsite.com">
                                    </use>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: the question is pretty confusing... it's not perfectly clear what you are asking for but probably the closest issue is having a `#toggle-download` button with a click event handler being a totally different element than the anchor element inside the `.box-content`. When you click on `to download center` it will actually visit the anchor href .. the `#toggle-download` is never engaged because anyway you get the same effect with the hovering (via mouseenter mouseleave). Can you please better focus your question?

Comment: plus it's not clear the relationship between your page and the Toggle device toolbar button in che chrome developer tools.. how does it trigger any behaviour in your page?

Comment: @DiegoD hi, you have to activate the  "toggle device Toolbar" in the DevTools in your browser, since mobile phones dont have hover effect, i tried to add a click toggle to my button to add "active" class to my elements, but when i tap the `#toggle-download` button in the mobile view, it calls this this link `<a href="/downloadcenter/">` which is not supposed to happen. the button is only supposed to add the active class  so that my `#download-box` slides open. then the user shall decide if he wants to tap the `to download center` to execute the link.

Comment: my conclusion now is that maybe the browser devTool is not the best implementation to test functions for phone devices. i implemented my localhost into an actual url and loaded the site on my phone, and i had no issues. i shall close this question right ?

Comment: I think the question is legit.. when you wrote your comment before it was more clear the issue you were dealing with. To narrow it down, it's about having a click event handler on a button that doesn't trigger when the element is tapped inside the browser's device simulator. I quickly tried with `touchstart` and it also didn't react properly. I'm not very familiar with mobile web dev.. so I'm not helpful here.. but you may better dig the matter of how it's better to deal with interactive elements engaged by the mobile screen actions (tap)

Comment: by the way, maybe the solution could be to select an actual device (not being just the `Responsive` label). That way it will mimic actual touch events

Comment: in cases of error you can try out the actual device as last resort, but i never thought id come across such problems, i wouldve never imagined that simple js function was going to react differently in the devTool based on the selected device. At the end this is a feature in the browser and cant really expect it to do all things.